# Disable/enable drag&drop support of Vaadin 8 grid at runtime

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, vaadin, vaadin8

I have a Vaadin 8 [Grid with drag&drop](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-dragndrop.html) support. Now I want to disable/reenable the drag&drop at runtime.

I tried setting the SelectionMode to None, but I am still able to drag&drop items. There also seems to be no method on the according classes to disable the drag&drop.

This is how I enabled drag&drop support:

```
GridDragSource<ItemA> availableItemsDragSource = new GridDragSource<>(availableItemsGrid);
GridDropTarget<ItemB> assignedItemsDropTarget = new GridDropTarget<>(assignedItemsGrid, DropMode.ON_TOP);
```

How can I disable drag&drop at runtime?

Comment: Please show what you did to enable D&D in the grid.

Comment: @AndréSchild sure, added the according source code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to disable the extension, by calling remove(), e.g. like

```
GridDragSource<ItemA> availableItemsDragSource = new GridDragSource<>(availableItemsGrid);
...
availableItemsDragSource.remove()
```

See the [JavaDoc](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.8.3/com/vaadin/ui/components/grid/GridDragSource.html#remove--) for more details.